# codeigniter ftp get filesize

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

How can i get remote file's file size  with codeigniter?
after making a connection , i want to get properties.xml file's size. in ordinery ftp i would get it with no problem but since i start using codeigniter it is kinda difficult.

this is in procedurel php ;

```
 $remote_filesize = ftp_size($conn_id, "properties.xml");
```

but how can i do it in codeigniter?

```
if($this->ftp->connect($config))
   {
     /*here some magic code*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this a small example

Controller_ftp.php

```
class Controller_ftp extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('ftp');
    }

    publilc function get_ftp_info(){
        $config['hostname'] = 'ftp.example.com';
        $config['username'] = 'your-username';
        $config['password'] = 'your-password';
        $config['debug']    = TRUE;

        foreach($this->ftp->list_files('/public_html/') as $item){
            $size = filesize($item);
            echo "name => $item - size => $size - etc <br>";
            clearstatcache();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use `$this->ftp->file_size($file)`, you need to extend ftp library and create the function retunring `filesize($item);`

Comment: If you want you can add the `$this->load->helper('number');` in the library extended or in ` $size = byte_format(filesize($item));`

Answer (score 0):

ok i went to library->ftp.php and basically added a function

```
public function get_conn_id()
{ return $this->conn_id;}
```

and later all i need to do was calling the function like this

```
$conn_id =  $this->ftp->get_conn_id();  
$remote_filesize = ftp_size($conn_id, "properties.xml");
```